# Flutter source - Future<String?>? Function(String)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I'm new to flutter?

Can someone explain to me what the following line of code means?

*typedef RecoverCallback = Future<String?>? Function(String);*
[image]

This line is contained in the auth.dart file of the flutter_login plugin
https://github.com/NearHuscarl/flutter_login/blob/master/lib/src/providers/auth.dart

So **Function(String)** Where is it implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
typedef RecoverCallback = Future<String?>? Function(String);
```

It's function-type alias, gives a function type a name that you can use when declaring fields and return types.

As you can see in 45 line of class Auth implementation, that function you need to pass to the constructor of

```
new Auth(onRecoverPassword: yourFunction);
```

yourFunction must be a Function that take some String parameter and return Future<String?> or null;

Answer (score 0):

The reason I want to understand the above line of code is because
**final error = await auth.onRecoverPassword!(auth.email);
error = null;**

but no mail is sent to **auth.email**.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).